# Different pid between NodeManager Managed Server and Java Process

Tags: weblogic, pid

On our Weblogic server, when the server goes OOM, the hprof file is generated with a pid java_pidA.hprof but there is another message from the Node Manager that says managed server ManagedServer_1 with pid pidB was shut down successfully.

Why are the PIDs different between the java process and the one reported by Node Manager?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a weblogic server there are always two PID. One for the script that starts the java virtual machine and another for the java virtual machine that runs the server.